# How to add an width 100% image to java emal MimeBodyPart?

Tags: jakarta-mail

Because I have a really wide image but the MimeBodyPart seems is limiting the image width.  I want my image width 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MimeBodyPart has nothing to do with this.  It's all up to the mail reader you're using how it chooses to display html body parts.  Most mail readers will limit the html you can use in a mail message.

You might find this [table of css support in mail readers](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) helpful.